# image row offset OpenGL

Tags: image, macos, opengl, printing, memory-alignment

I am developing (Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)) a graphical (basically Cocoa) OSX (10.9.3 (13D65)) app using OpenGL graphics. I am targeting the app for general availability on any modern MacBook platform. I'm down to the proverbial "last bug" which arises in the code that allows users to print graphical results of the analyses. I use the usual machinery to steer execution to print logic in my `NSOpenGLView` subclass. The overall approach is to fill a buffer with `glReadPixels` and then render it in an `NSBitMapImage`. The rest of the code deals with a TIFF representation of that image, as an `NSImage`, ultimately scaling it and sending it to the print machinery.

This always works on my own MacBook Pro (13", 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 4000) but fails for some images on a client machine with a Retina display. It exhibits the failure by producing a print image with successive rows of the print output increasingly wrapped a bit to the right (this site doesn't count me as being responsible enough to post images). The resultant image has the appearance of a planar image being viewed from an oblique angle with parts of the image wrapped out of place.

This is certainly an alignment issue of some kind, and I've done my best both to research and experiment my way out of it, to no avail.

Here is the core image-building code (within my `NSOpenGLView` subclass) that produces a TIFF image from the view:

```
- (NSData*) makeTIFFFromThisView
{
    const double scaleMultiplier = highResScale_;
    unsigned char* planes[1];
    NSInteger length = 0;
    NSImage*  image = nil;
    NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = nil;
    NSSize    size = { 0.0, 0.0 };  // these are float values.
    NSMutableData* buffer = nil;
    SInt16  _myglWidth = [self bounds].size.width,
            _myglHeight = [self bounds].size.height;

    assert(_myglWidth > 0);
    assert(_myglHeight > 0);

    size.width = _myglWidth * scaleMultiplier;
    size.height = _myglHeight * scaleMultiplier;
    length = (unsigned int)(size.height * size.width * 3);

    assert(length > 0);

    buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength :length];
    assert(buffer != nil);

    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4); // force 4 byte alignment

    // WARNING: glReadPixels has arguments defined in PIXEL dimensions

    glReadPixels(0, 0, _myglWidth * scaleMultiplier, _myglHeight * scaleMultiplier, GL_RGB,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 [buffer mutableBytes]);
    planes[0] = (unsigned char*)[buffer mutableBytes]; // illegal conversion from NSMutableData to unsigned int

    // bytesPerRow has to include some extra words to accommodate memory alignment; that's
    // the reason for the funny +align. (Well, it works. Sometimes.)

    const NSInteger align = _myglWidth % 4;
    bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes :planes
                                                     pixelsWide :_myglWidth * scaleMultiplier
                                                     pixelsHigh :_myglHeight * scaleMultiplier
                                                  bitsPerSample :8
                                                samplesPerPixel :3
                                                       hasAlpha :NO
                                                       isPlanar :NO
                                                 colorSpaceName :NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                    bytesPerRow :(_myglWidth * scaleMultiplier * 3) + align
                                                   bitsPerPixel :24];
    image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize :size];
    [image setFlipped :YES];
    [image lockFocus];
    [bitmap drawInRect :NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [image unlockFocus];

    return [image TIFFRepresentation];
}
```

The `scaleMultiplier` / `highResScale_` identifiers are empirically derived from the platform, and are used to adjust image resolution (viz., `[openGLFrame_ convertSizeToBacking: CGSizeMake(1,1)].width`).

Adding the `align` kludge makes things better for some images on my normal MacBook display but still leaves the leaves a row-by-row horizontal shift in many images that are generated on a Retina machine. I haven't been able to correlate specific properties of the images to the failure modes, though early on there appeared to be a trend pointing to problems correlating to prime factors of the row size.

Here is additional code (within my `NSOpenGLView` subclass) that invokes the above method:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay: YES]; // make sure view is up to date
NSData* viewTIFF = [self makeTIFFFromThisView];

// Save a copy for a debugging peek
if([viewTIFF writeToFile : @"/tmp/TEMP.tiff" atomically:NO]==NO){
    NSRunAlertPanel(nil, NSLocalizedString(@"Cannot save file '%@' : %s", nil),nil,nil,nil,
                    @"/tmp/TEMP.tiff", strerror(errno));
}

NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData: viewTIFF];
const NSSize imageSize = [theImage size];
const double aspectRatio = imageSize.height / imageSize.width;

// targetSize represents the size of the output medium
NSSize targetSize = { 600, 600 };
targetSize.height = aspectRatio * targetSize.width;

theImage = [theImage imageByScalingProportionallyToSize: targetSize];

NSRect theFrame;
theFrame.origin.x = theFrame.origin.y = -1000.0;   // draw offscreen
theFrame.size = targetSize;
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: theFrame];
[imageView setImage: theImage];

NSPrintOperation *const op = imageView? [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView: imageView]: nil;

if (op) {
    [self massagePrintInfoFor: op];

    const BOOL success = [op runOperation];

    retval = success && op && [op printInfo] && [[op printInfo] printer] && [[[op printInfo] printer] name]?
    [[[op printInfo] printer] name]: nil;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This padding byte calculation:

```
const NSInteger align = _myglWidth % 4;
```

is wrong. There are two issues here:

1. For the alignment, the actual bytes are relevant, but `_myglWidth` is the width in *pixels*.
2. The calculation is wrong in princriple: The byte offset from one pixel row has to be a multiple of the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`. The modulo is not correct here. If your row would be 3 bytes without padding, you're missung just 1 padding byte to make it divisible by 4, not 3%4==3. You could use `4 - (x % 4)`, but that has the special case that it will evaluate to 4 where 0 would be appropriate, so the correct variant is `(4 - (x % 4)) % 4`. This can be improved by replacing the modulo with a bitwise and, and the alignment will always be some power of two.

To correct both, I suggest the following:

```
const NSInteger align = (4 - ((_myglWidth * scaleMultiplier * 3)  & 3)) & 3;
```

Comment: My next idea was going to be the 4 - ... again, but that `_myglWidth` is in pixels totally eluded me (doh) and I never would have discovered the problem with the zero modulus — that was probably the killer. My highest accolades to you if this works. I've put in the fix and have shipped it (with a perfunctory 'int' cast) out to our beta sites — I'll be back. I'm pretty new here — what's the highest accolade I can accord you here?  :-) Mange tai / many thanks

Comment: Beta sites checked in, and I'm now bug free — and they're complaining only that they want new features. Thanks again.